# How to test pagination when the pagination link is based on content

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i have to test pagination in our website the problem is the pagination links appears only when the user has more than 12 messages otherwise no pagination links.

1. How to test this scenario
2. What are the things i look for

Comment: Maybe try http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ but you will need to work on your question. You haven't shown what you've done yourself so far.

Answer (score -1):

You question isn't very clear...

Pseudocode:

```
if(user.postcount >= 12){
    displayPagination();
}
displayTheRest();
```

Answer (score -1):

set for 2 message your code or if you have only two question then check by 1 message  and apply check in listing only one message come on one page hope it make sense